# Including quarters with no data in quarterly report in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Currently we are generating a quarterly report for the specified criteria. The output of the data will look like below

```
"data":
           [
               {
                   "group": "2014-Apr-2014-Jun",
                   "count": 944
               },
               {
                   "group": "2014-Jan-2014-Mar",
                   "count": 154
               },
               {
                   "group": "2013-Oct-2013-Dec",
                   "count": 895
               }
           ]
```

We need to make a change to include quarters which does not have any data the output will look like below

```
"data":
               [
                   {
                       "group": "2014-Oct-2014-Dec",
                       "count": 0
                   },
                   {
                       "group": "2014-Jul-2014-Sep",
                       "count": 0
                   },
                   {
                       "group": "2014-Apr-2014-Jun",
                       "count": 944
                   },
                   {
                       "group": "2014-Jan-2014-Mar",
                       "count": 154
                   },
                   {
                       "group": "2013-Oct-2013-Dec",
                       "count": 895
                   }
               ]
```

Below is the query which I'm using to generate this report

```
SELECT cast(year([job].jobdate) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-' + -- gives year
       cast(left(datename(month, DATEADD(q, DATEDIFF(q, 0, [job].jobdate), 0)), 3) AS VARCHAR(3)) + '-' + -- gives start month of the quarter
       cast(year([job].jobdate) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-' +  -- gives year
       cast(left(datename(month, dateadd(d, - 1, dateadd(q, DATEDIFF(q, 0, [job].jobdate) + 1, 0))), 3) AS VARCHAR(3)) AS 'group' -- gives end month of the quarter
    ,count([job].bgtjobid) AS 'count'
FROM dbo.job [job] WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE (
        [job].jobdate >= '2013-10-01'
        AND [job].jobdate <= '2014-12-31'
        )
    AND (1 = 1)
GROUP BY cast(year([job].jobdate) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-' + 
            cast(left(datename(month, DATEADD(q, DATEDIFF(q, 0, [job].jobdate), 0)), 3) AS VARCHAR(3)) + '-' + 
            cast(year([job].jobdate) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-' + 
            cast(left(datename(month, dateadd(d, - 1, dateadd(q, DATEDIFF(q, 0, [job].jobdate) + 1, 0))), 3) AS VARCHAR(3))
```

Answers with sub queries are welcome but I'm really looking to do this without any sub queries since it will make the Query Builder in my application little messy

I have also included the SQL fiddle for this.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a769f/1

On running the above query we will get the result as below

```
|             GROUP | COUNT |
|-------------------|-------|
| 2013-Oct-2013-Dec |     3 |
| 2014-Apr-2014-Jun |     2 |
| 2014-Jan-2014-Mar |     3 |
| 2014-Jul-2014-Sep |     3 |
```

Since i don't have the data for the last quarter it is excluded now i need to make the query to include the last quarter with 0

```
|             GROUP | COUNT |
|-------------------|-------|
| 2013-Oct-2013-Dec |     3 |
| 2014-Apr-2014-Jun |     2 |
| 2014-Jan-2014-Mar |     3 |
| 2014-Jul-2014-Sep |     3 |
| 2014-Oct-2014-Dec |     0 |
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Add an sqlfiddler sample data with current query you are using. Then only there is a way to check it.

Comment: @Veera I have not used SQL fiddle before. But created one since you asked Please check the updated question for the URL. Please let me know if you need any other info

Comment: From your sql Fiddler link I updated the result. verify it http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a769f/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just RUN the below code to get the result you want. Also, When you want to change the date range on generating report, Change  @start and @end dates.

```
DECLARE @start DATETIME, @end DATETIME

SET @start = '2013-10-01'
SET @end = '2014-12-31'

;WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT dt = DATEADD(DAY, -(DAY(@start) - 1), @start)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, 1, dt)
    FROM cte
    WHERE dt < DATEADD(DAY, -(DAY(@end) - 1), @end)
)

SELECT Group1, Sum(count1) AS Count
FROM
(
SELECT cast(year([job].jobdate) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-' + -- gives year
       cast(left(datename(month, DATEADD(q, DATEDIFF(q, 0, [job].jobdate), 0)), 3) AS VARCHAR(3)) + '-' + -- gives start month of the quarter
       cast(year([job].jobdate) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-' +  -- gives year
       cast(left(datename(month, dateadd(d, - 1, dateadd(q, DATEDIFF(q, 0, [job].jobdate) + 1, 0))), 3) AS VARCHAR(3)) AS 'group1' -- gives end month of the quarter
    ,count([job].bgtjobid) AS 'count1'
FROM job [job] WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE (
        [job].jobdate >= @start
        AND [job].jobdate <= @end
        )
    AND (1 = 1)
GROUP BY cast(year([job].jobdate) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-' + 
            cast(left(datename(month, DATEADD(q, DATEDIFF(q, 0, [job].jobdate), 0)), 3) AS VARCHAR(3)) + '-' + 
            cast(year([job].jobdate) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-' + 
            cast(left(datename(month, dateadd(d, - 1, dateadd(q, DATEDIFF(q, 0, [job].jobdate) + 1, 0))), 3) AS VARCHAR(3))
UNION
  select distinct cast(year(dt) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-' + -- gives year
       cast(left(datename(month, DATEADD(q, DATEDIFF(q, 0, dt), 0)), 3) AS VARCHAR(3)) + '-' + -- gives start month of the quarter
       cast(year(dt) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-' +  -- gives year
       cast(left(datename(month, dateadd(d, - 1, dateadd(q, DATEDIFF(q, 0, dt) + 1, 0))), 3) AS VARCHAR(3)) AS 'group1' -- gives end month of the quarter
    ,0 AS 'count1'
FROM cte
) as A
GROUP BY  Group1
```

[--Quick Demo Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1b92c/1)